# Using yaml file and boto3 provision linux server on aws cloud

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I have been provided following yaml file and asked to provision linux server which reflects following condition using boto3.

I am unsure how to consume yaml file to create linux instance in boto3. I know we can consume yaml file in cloudformation but this is new.

I am not asking how to open/read yaml file. I am looking on approach why do we need yaml input in boto3.

**yaml file**

```yaml
server:

  vcpu_count: 2

  memory_size_gb: 2

  volumes:

    - device: /dev/xvda

      size_gb: 10

      type: ext4

      mount: /

    - device: /dev/xvdf

      size_gb: 100

      type: xfs

      mount: /data

  users:

    - login: user1

      ssh_key: <user ssh public key goes here> user1@localhost
```

Comment: What application is this yaml file from? Its not CloudFormation, terraform.

Comment: I am provided this yaml in technical challenge. No other information is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to read a yaml file?

```py
import yaml
with open("yourfile.yml", "rt") as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)
# do something with "data"
```

Once you've got the file loaded head off to [boto3 - EC2 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html) and create the instance as described in the file.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, this looks similar to launching an ec2 instance. If you agree, then [this link](https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-create-an-ec2-instance-with-python) might help.

The other configurations can be setup with the boto3 documentation link provided in the previous answer.

Comment: I know how can I create ec2 instance using boto3. What I am looking for specifically is what way I can use this provided yaml file as input and provision ec2 instance on aws.